# ERC721. Why owner is not approved

Tags: solidity, nft, erc-721

i writte smart contract - auction of nft. You can see code here: https://pastebin.com/rTQHcLHh

So, i have `Users` contract. There i have `connectUser` method, it add new `User` by msg.sender in mapping. Also here is `nftInstance` and `auctionInstance` - `User` contract has access to this.

There are `collectItem` in `User` contract - create nft FOR USERADDRES (not user contract address) in nftInstance and save it in mapping, `sellItem` - create auction in auctionInstance, and placeBid

There is problem. There is `finalizeAuction` method. It transfers nft to `highestBidder` address. But i get error - ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved. So, in remix i call ownerOf this nft - it's userAddres (it is saved in `User` contract on init, see code). But if i call method `isApproveForAll`, i understand that owner is not the user, but a user contract. Try it yourself!

How to fix that?? I can't understand it;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code smell on your code is very strong. I looked around and it is a lot of back and forth trying to understand. You are overcomplicating everything. I think you come from a Java world (me too).

For instance, this function does not improve the code:

```
function itemApproving(address approved) public {
    setApprovalForAll(approved, true);
}
```

Just use `setApprovalForAll(approved, true);` everywhere instead of `itemApproving(approved);`.

Talking about this `setApprovalForAll`. It has to be called by the owner of the NFT to do what you expect it to do. It cannot be called by random addresses. However, inside `Auction.finalizeAuction` you call it, so in effect it is the `Auction` instance that is asking to `setApprovalForAll`. Ok, it is not forbidden to do.

But! Later the same `Auction` instance does `nftInstance.itemTransfer(owner,...`. This is where it does not work, the auction instance is not allowed to effect the transfer.

You got the meaning of `setApprovalForAll` in reverse. It is the `owner` who has to call `setApprovalForAll(auction.address, true)` in a transaction of its own, sometime before the auction resolves.

---

For the same reason in `User.sellItem`, when you do:

```
nftInstance.itemApproving(
    address(auctionInstance.getAuctionById(auctionId))
)
```

It is not the real owner that did `setApproval`, but the `User` instance.

---

Further simplify your contracts. A sample:

1. You don't need `UserData.exists`. It can be replaced by `address(UserData.User) != address(0)`.
2. In effect, you can reduce your `mapping(address => UserData)` to `mapping(address => User)`.
3. Do you really need a `User` contract?
4. Doing an unbounded loop like `for (uint256 i = 0; i < userTokenIdsCount` is a big no-no. Get a better data structure instead.
5. All your string operations can probably be sent off-chain.
6. `getRandomNumber()` is not really random. It just opens new issues or attack vectors when a user calls it twice in a block, or when a sophisticated attacker knows what value it will have.

Comment: Okay, thanks you. I try to solve this problen for week:) I add itemApproving when trying to solve it. Yes, i know about `getRandomNumber`, i try chainlink, but it's pretty complex logic for this project. But where do i need to call `setApproveForAll` to transfer nft? Before i try to make the chain of approving: nft -> user -> auctions -> auction, but it's wrong?

Comment: maybe i don't need to create any approve methods in contract? Instead should i call `setApproveForAll` directly in NFT contract from user's wallet?

Comment: ---Instead should i call setApproveForAll directly in NFT contract from user's wallet?---   Yes.